# What determines the order of messages returned by a Kafka consumer subscribed to multiple topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I did some testing with a Kafka consumer where I subscribed to two topics. I tested swapping the order of the topics listed in the container, and did not find that the results observed changed.

This lead me to ask the question, *What determines the ordering of messages returned by a Kafka consumer which subscribes to multiple topics?*

To add further context, the program I drafted was written in Rust. The names of topics were strings contained in a `Vec` container. The order of the elements in this vector did not seem to change the ordering of returned messages.

I also wrote a producer which produced blocks of 10 messages to each of the topics. 10 events to Topic A, 10 to Topic B, repeat...

I suspect that the ordering is determined by the timestamp of the log files. Kafka writes messages to log files which are timestamped by creation time on disk. I have a feeling that while events from both log files (think: topics, partitions) are returned in a defined order (FIFO) which log file is read from first is determined by which has the earlier creation timestamp. I don't know how this would scale if a partition/topic was split into multiple files because the size/time is exceeded.

- Kafka writes messages to topics
- Topics are partitioned by key
- If the key is the same or there is one partition per topic, as in this case, then topic and partition use the same file to store their log
- This underlying file structure is configurable to split into multiple files by the maximum file size and also by time. Eg: Split every 24h etc.
- I did not change these default settings
- When creating the consumer, I was reading from the earliest message